# Join and dividing elements

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, material-design, css-animations

I'm developing a website using react and mdl.
And I'm looking through the material design of google and I have come across Joining and Dividing elements:
https://material.google.com/motion/transforming-material.html#transforming-material-joining-dividing

I tried to do this thing, but the shadows of an element always appears above sibling elements, which is exactly what shouldn't happen.

How can I make this work? and prevent the shadow on an element from appearing above its sibling?

Update :
As for right now I just tried to prevent the shadow from appearing above its sibling with simple html divs.

Html:

```
<div>
Some Text
</div>
<div>
Some Text
</div>
<div>
Some Text
</div>
<div>
Some Text
</div>
<div>
Some Text
</div>
```

Css:

```
div {
  background-color:white;
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 5px black;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/81t4v4a5/

Comment: Could you please put your code? CSS, React, JSX?

Comment: @lhrec_106 updated the question.